# Does General Relativity say that the Laws of Physics are the same in all Reference Frames?

Tags: general-relativity

Most texts on General Relativity seem to imply that Einstein generalized the Relativity Principle (that all reference frames are equivalent) to include changes in velocity (accelerations); but then go on to the talk solely about Gravity.  What about other types of acceleration, like life on a rotating disk? or aboard an aircraft during turbulence?

Answer (score 2):

In General Relativity the inertial frames are infinitesimally small regions of spacetime.

So you can pick any coordinate system you want, and any sufficiently smooth frame that has a future pointing timelike vector a point, then the family of infinitesimal inertial frames at that point will have one that is instantaneously comoving with that timelike vector. So in a sense you can use that frame by using the infinitesimal frame that matches up to it.

It is also possible to use frames that don't have future pointing timelike vectors. For sufficiently generalized definitions of frames (as opposed to coordinates) you can have more than four vectors at every point. So lots of possibilities are possible.

But you could already do these things in special relativity if you want to include all the required effort. Writing your equations to be invariant under an arbitrarily change of coordinates isn't really physics it is just writing things in a coordinate independent way.

The physical content of general relativity are things like that matter moves on geodesics or that the spacetime metric evolves so as to satisfy Einstein's Field Equation.